How to setup a node in a blockchain node?
How to setup a node in a blockchain for free ?I want a step by step guide and resource to deploy a node.
I have tried Puppeth but it is out of service since January 2023, and I have also tried some of the nodes but I am unable to proceed.

As far as I know Puppeth is a Geth Ethereum network. But as you've mentioned most services are a bit resource expensive.

If you are looking for running a node in blockchain with budget, then I would advice to try Cosmos chain (Cosmos network): which has IBC protocol, Cosmos SDK, Tendermint BFT. And more importantly most resources are able to run in Testnet network for free.

Permissioned blockchain in other words Hyperledger based nodes (hyperledger.org) mostly used for research purposes (not for business compared to Cosmos chain). Most of the resources are open and easy to follow the guide


